# Losing Secure Cookies when switching from https to http and back to https

Tags: asp.net, http, cookies, https

I'm creating `Secure Session Cookies` in ASP.NET . 
The cookies are working fine as long as I switch between all the `https` pages , As soon as I go to `http` I lose the Secure cookie which is expected I believe but when I come back to `https` the cookie is still lost .
Am I missing something ? Any place that I can look to what exactly is happening or is this expected behavior ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no issue as such , the value of cookie was getting overridden . Ideally secure cookies will be available for secure pages.